# How to clone an existing blob to an Input Asset with Azure Media Services v3

Tags: azure-functions, azure-media-services, azure-blob-trigger

I'm trying to create a Blob Trigger that will start an Media Service job when a video is uploaded to a specific container. I can't figure out how to create an input asset from that blob within the function app. There is clear documentation on this for AMS v2 but I can't seem to find anything helpful for v3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a look at this repo of Azure Function samples?
I recommend asking questions on the Issues list there as well.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/tree/master/LiveAndVodDRMOperationsV3

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/blob/master/LiveAndVodDRMOperationsV3/LiveAndVodDRMOperationsV3/VodFunctions/start-blob-copy-to-asset.cs

See the start-blob-copy-to-asset function, that may be useful for you.